# save user email before leaving page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On the cart page of my website, I have to intercept the user leaving the page and ask them if they want to save their cart via email.

I guess I have to use the event "beforeunload" to intercept the user leaving the page, but then I have two problems:

- How to exclude from the "beforeunload" trigger the click on the link to proceed with the payment?
- How to prompt a small form where I can ask for his email (to be used somehow later) and then proceed with the unload of the page?

Comment: I just started thinking about this, so I have no interesting code to submit at this moment

Comment: Did you check out how others (magento, oxid, shopware) have done this?

Answer (score 1):

For excluding on the link to proceed with the payment, you can do this :-

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "You're leaving the site.";
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel!=ext]').click(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
    $('form').submit(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing u can do is making a default browser messagebox appears...

```
window.onbeforeunload = foo;

function foo(e) {
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

        //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
}
```